# javascript changing image src attribute

Tags: javascript

I have created a function add element to click event listener. It is supposed to be change img src attribute but at least one element doesnt change src attribute when I add a few new items

the code is like that:

```
function updateCheckButtons(){
        let checkButtons= document.querySelectorAll(".uncheck");
        checkButtons.forEach(chk=>{
            chk.addEventListener("click",function(){
               let src=chk.getAttribute("src");
               if(src.endsWith("unchecked.png")){
                chk.setAttribute("src","images/checked.png")
               }
               else {
                chk.setAttribute("src","images/unchecked.png")
               }
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Your code iterates through *all* of your buttons, old ones and new ones. When you call `.addEventListener()`, it will always add a new event handler *without removing handlers that are already there*.  Thus, the "old" buttons may have two copies of the handler, so the first one will change the image, and then the next one will change it back.

Comment: Can you update this to a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what isn't working as expected in that example?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to toggle an image from checked/unchecked, I would first name my functions more meaningfully.

Now, I would store the images in a state array. The unchecked state should be at index 0, and the checked should be at index 1. You can now use modular arithmetic to cycle through the images.

```js
const imgState = [
  'https://img.icons8.com/?id=19336&format=png', // off
  'https://img.icons8.com/?id=25534&format=png', // on
];

enableClickListeners('.uncheck', handleClick);

function handleClick({ target: chk }) {
  const currentIndex = imgState.indexOf(chk.getAttribute('src'));
  chk.setAttribute('src', nextState(imgState, currentIndex));
}

function nextState(states, currentIndex) {
  return states[(currentIndex + 1) % states.length];
}

function enableClickListeners(selector, ...eventListeners) {
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(el => {
    eventListeners.forEach(eventListener => {
      el.addEventListener('click', eventListener);
    });
  })
}

function disableClickListeners(selector, ...eventListeners) {
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(el => {
    eventListeners.forEach(eventListener => {
      el.removeEventListener('click', eventListener);
    });
  })
}
```

```css
.uncheck {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<img class="uncheck" src="https://img.icons8.com/?id=25534&format=png"/>
<img class="uncheck" src="https://img.icons8.com/?id=19336&format=png" />
<img class="uncheck" src="https://img.icons8.com/?id=19336&format=png" />
```

Now, what I would recommend is that you use data attributes + CSS to style the checkboxes. The checkbox should be represented as a `<span>` or `<div>`, and the image should be a CSS background image.

The added benefits of data attributes are:

- They are more meaningful, manageable, and readable
- No need to juggle CSS classes around
- Can get the state through HTML or JS

```js
enableClickListeners('.uncheck', handleClick);

function handleClick({ target: chk }) {
  const isChecked = chk.dataset.checked === 'true';
  chk.dataset.checked = !isChecked;
}

function enableClickListeners(selector, ...eventListeners) {
  for (let el of document.querySelectorAll(selector)) {
    for (let eventListener of eventListeners) {
      el.addEventListener('click', eventListener);
    }
  }
}

function disableClickListeners(selector, ...eventListeners) {
  for (let el of document.querySelectorAll(selector)) {
    for (let eventListener of eventListeners) {
      el.removeEventListener('click', eventListener);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.uncheck {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: url('https://img.icons8.com/?id=19336&format=png&size=32');
}

.uncheck[data-checked="true"] {
  background-image: url('https://img.icons8.com/?id=25534&format=png&size=32');
}

.uncheck:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span class="uncheck" data-checked="true"></span>
<span class="uncheck"></span>
<span class="uncheck"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Thank you. Instead of calling the addEventFunction for every item when adding them dynamically, which handles both old and new items, I created a function that addresses and adds an event handler only for the last item. This approach resolved the issue. that is the working code

```
   function updateCheckButtons(){
    let checkButtons= document.querySelectorAll(".uncheck");
    checkButtons[checkButtons.length-1].addEventListener("click",function(){
         let src=  checkButtons[checkButtons.length-1].getAttribute("src");
         if(src=="images/unchecked.png"){
            checkButtons[checkButtons.length-1].setAttribute("src","images/checked.png")
           }
           else {
            checkButtons[checkButtons.length-1].setAttribute("src","images/unchecked.png")
           }
    })
```